# Manual login/authenticationManager - Spring security 6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

There is a [section into the Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html#store-authentication-manually) where it is written:

*In some cases, for example, you might be authenticating a user manually instead of relying on Spring Security filters.*

The sample code is given below:

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public void login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) { 
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(
        loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()); 
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(token); 
    SecurityContext context = securityContextHolderStrategy.createEmptyContext();
    context.setAuthentication(authentication); 
    securityContextHolderStrategy.setContext(authentication);
    securityContextRepository.saveContext(context, request, response); 
}
```

The documentation thought is very shy about how can we inject the correct `authenticationManager`. Spring won't autowire it. In my understanding we have a hierarchy of many `AuthenticationManager`-s (common implementation is `ProviderManager`) as shown below.

[image: ProviderManagers]

I'm definitely not sure how to grab the correct one. Any idea how to make this sample code work?

Answer (score 2):

You can create `AuthenticationManager` bean like in the following snippet. A list of all existing `AuthenticationProvider` beans will be passed as an input parameter.

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(List<AuthenticationProvider> authenticationProviders) {
    return new ProviderManager(authenticationProviders);
}
```

If you have a `UserDetailsService`, you can create a `DaoAuthenticationProvider` bean and it will be used as one of the authentication providers in that list.

```
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder encoder) {
   DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
   authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
   authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder);
   return authProvider;
}
```

Please do not forget that these methods should be in a class annotated with `@Configuration`

Comment: The `List<AuthenticationProvider> authenticationProviders` is empty in a standard setup. Not 100% sure why do you think the providers should be exposed as managed beans...

Comment: Usually you are the one who expose them as beans, like DaoAuthenticationProvider in my example

Answer (score 1):

When I don't want to instantiate a new `ProviderManager` and want to use the same `AuthenticationProvider`list that the `SecurityFilterChain` uses, this is how I obtain the `AuthenticationManager`.

```
private AuthenticationManager authManager;

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    DefaultSecurityFilterChain filterChain = http
    
        ...
        ...
        
        .build();
        
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder =
        http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
    authManager = authenticationManagerBuilder.getOrBuild();
    return filterChain;
}

@DependsOn("securityFilterChain")
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager exposeAuthenticationManger(){
    return authManager;
}
```

This might not be the ideal solution, but it works. Hope someone finds it useful.